# Cordova - some Android phones ignoring autocapitalize=off for textarea's

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have very simple HTML in my Cordova app for users to input an email and a password.  I use two textarea's so I can better control the styling.

```
 <textarea placeholder="password" id="accountPassword" class="customInput login" rows="1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

What I've found is that this works fine on iOS but some Android devices (pretty rare apparently) ignore the autocapitalize.  I've had Android users report the problem and have now been able to isolate it while testing on a Sony Xperia (European version) running Android 7 (on a testing device farm site).

I've tried several suggestions I found on the web (adding a name field to the textarea, using `autocapitalize="none"`, simplifying the textarea) and nothing helps.  By the way, if I change to a regular input field, `autocapitalize="off"` works fine (on the Xperia) but my customer doesn't want that.

Thanks! Jon

Answer (score 0):

To prevent textarea to capitalize, you easily can add a class like this:

```
.myTextArea{
   text-transform: lowercase
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  It's a password entry field so the user is allowed to enter mixed case.  Also when I test it on the Sony phone in the device farm, the first character still defaults to upper case - but when I type it in, it changes to lowercase.  Great idea though.

Comment: Aaah i understand the situation! you just need to prevent the capitalization at init, but maybe they need to use Upper case letter in the middle of the password, right? Sorry, my bad,  i will see if there is another solution so! :)